# JSONStorage issue in PIG

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

**STORE A INTO 'output/abc/json' USING JsonStorage(Name:chararray, SOCIE:chararray);**

When I run this I get error :-

pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'JsonStorage' with arguments

**However It works if I dont pass the schema**

STORE A INTO 'output/abc/json' USING JsonStorage();

Please advise how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

JsonStorage doesn't require schema. See PIG documentation here [JsonStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore)

Comment: Well, does that mean JsonStorage doesnt allow schema declaration?

Comment: Of course JsonStorage needs a schema! Data must have the schema. Read source at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/JsonStorage.java